# bash grep results with var value changing each line

Tags: bash, grep, var

I want to print to the screen my grep results, I need it to print in each line some var value and then at the same line one of grep results and so on, my lines should look like that:

> CurrentURL line number:expression found

the line number and expression I already have, it's the grep command, just need help with the var
in which CurrentURL will be before each grep line.
thanks.

p.s

> if [ "$ExpressionValue" == "email" ];then
>
> ```
>   ExpressionValue='([[:alnum:]_.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,6})'
>   grep -E -n -o $ExpressionValue $INDEX
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>   grep -n -o -a $ExpressionValue $INDEX
> ```
>
> fi

and results should look like that:

```
{URL} {line number}:{expression}
```

urls will come from the var i want before each grep line, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you show us the script you're working with, along with an example of what the results should look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily with `(g)awk` like:

```
 export URL="SET_YOUR_URL_HERE"
 awk -v U="${URL}" '/YOUR_SEARCHPATTERN/ {print U " " NR " " $0}' INPUT_FILE
```

If the search pattern is dynamic:

```
 export URL="SET_YOUR_URL_HERE"
 awk -v U="${URL}" -v PATTERN="YOUR_SEARCHPATTERN" '$0 ~ PATTERN {print U " " NR " " $0}' INPUT_FILE
```

If you want to print the matching pattern only:

```
awk -v U="${URL}" -v PATTERN="YOUR_SEARCHPATTERN" '$0 ~ PATTERN {print U " " NR " " gensub(".*(" PATTERN ").*","\\1","g",$0)}' INPUT_FILE
```

*Note:* the above solution will print only one occurrence per line!

With `grep`:

```
 export URL="SET_YOUR_URL_HERE"
 grep -n PATTERN INPUT_FILE | while read line ; do
      printf "%s\t%s" "${URL}" "${line}"
 done
```

HTH

Comment: I have dinamic pattern, it's a var value, the awk thing is nice, but i need to show only the matching expression not the whole line, as -o in grep do , it's possible?